# Visual Studio 2010 won't compile/create new projects

Tags: visual-studio-2010, compile

My Visual Studio 2010 Professional with SP1 installed won't compile anymore.
The shown error is:

```
TRACKER : error TRK0005: Failed to locate: "CL.exe". 
The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Strangely it is also not possible anymore to create new projects - the wizard appears but just restarts when I press create.
As I found out the paths for Visual Studio are now built from settings in the registry. Namely
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio`. 
Comparing a colleagues installation with mine revealed no different settings.
So this is how the `Property Pages/Configuration Properties/VC++ Directories` look like:

```
Executable Directories: $(ExecutablePath)
Include Directories: $(IncludePath)
Reference Directories: $(ReferencePath)
Library Directories: $(LibraryPath)
Source Directories: $(SourcePath)
Exclude Directories: $(ExcludePath)
```

From the `Visual Studio 2010 Command Prompt`, `cl.exe` is found.

I can only guess that this behavior was caused by a reinstallation of Studio a couple of months ago (to a different folder). As we use an external build-script for our main project there is a good chance that it is broken since then.

Any hints?

Comment: Are you sure you installed all the required features?  `cl.exe` is the Visual Studio C/C++ compiler & linker.  Make sure you added VC++ support, and not just C# and the other languages.

Comment: C++ support is added. I doubt that I would see the C++ templates if it was not installed.

Answer (score 3):

#### Compilation issue

After some further research I found this [question](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/br/vssetup/thread/2ead013f-c3c8-430d-a8af-a087edc1a6d7) on MSDN. 
The answer from a Microsoft employee contained some tips how to debug your VS installation. Namely:

- Run as administrator.
- Start from command line:

  - `Devenv.exe /log C:\VS_error.log`
  - `Devenv.exe /Resetsettings`
  - `Devenv.exe /ResetSkipPkgs`
  - `Devenv.exe /Safemode`
  - `Devenv.exe /Resetsettings`
- Reboot OS to safe mode.
- Use [Process Monitor](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/br/vssetup/thread/2ead013f-c3c8-430d-a8af-a087edc1a6d7) to see what VS is trying to do.

None of this helped so I went for a repair installation of VS 2010 and SP1 - it didn't help. After that I reset the settings - didn't help.
What got me going again is opening `Property Pages` of my project, then `Configuration Properties/General/Platform Toolset`. Here are three options listed in my installation:

- v100
- v90
- Windows7.1SDK

The active one was `v100` so I switched to `v90`. With that toolset VS is able to compile again. Obviously this is not a good solution because the 9 compiler is not the latest compiler so this is a mere workaround for my problem.

#### Project creation issue

The repair install for VS didn't help here either. This [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5610471/cannot-create-a-new-project-of-any-type-in-vs-2010) solved a part of the problem. After adding `.vbproj` and `vcproj` to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes` in the registry, I was able to create Visual Basic and C# projects again. But still I can't create any C++ projects.

Because of the drawbacks of the solution I will not mark my answer as solution to the problem. To me it looks like the registry is messed up and I would appreciate to get to know the source of my problems.

Comment: Have you tried a full uninstall/reinstall?